# Swagger specification for anything other than HTTP GET

Tags: rest, http-post, swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-2.0

I'm busy understanding how the swagger.json specification works (in my case it's api.json). While researching, I could find numerous examples of how to handle GET requests but nothing for POST or anything else. My immediate need is to implement the POST part but I feel like I need to understand this better instead of copying and pasting code and relying on trial and error to make it work. The content in the Swagger.io website is not beginner friendly. Can someone explain what is going on in the example code below, particularly after the 'get:' in both cases:

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "FoodTrucks",
"description": "An TryApp sample API App where you can find Food trucks."
},
"host": "microsoft-apiapp1fe6951749ff4b76b8cc9194bc29ba61.azurewebsites.net:443",
"schemes": ["http", "https"],
"basePath": "/api/data",
"paths": {
    "/foodtrucks": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["FoodTrucks"],
            "operationId": "getFoodTrucks",
            "consumes": [],
            "produces": ["application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/xml",
            "text/xml"],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Restaurant"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "deprecated": false
        }
    },
    "/foodtrucks/{id}": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["FoodTrucks"],
            "operationId": "getFoodTruckDetails",
            "consumes": [],
            "produces": ["application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/xml",
            "text/xml"],
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "id",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            }],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Restaurant"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "deprecated": false
        }
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "Restaurant": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "format": "int32",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "likes": {
                "format": "int32",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "savory": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "sweet": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "vegetarian": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "bookable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Please can you help with a simple POST example as well.

Answer (score 2):

Swagger's [extended examples](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json) include POSTs. Here is a sample with a block-by-block explanation:

```
"post": {
    "description": "Creates a new pet in the store.  Duplicates are allowed",
```

Description is a friendly explanation for the operation taken mostly from the [documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/#operationObject).

```
    "operationId": "addPet",
```

OperationId is a friendly name for the operation. Must be unique.

```
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
```

Produces is the MIME type of the endpoint's output

```
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "pet",
        "in": "body",
        "description": "Pet to add to the store",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/NewPet"
```

Schema references ($ref) refers to the data type definition in the "definitions" block. Refer to the NewPet section in [this JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json).

```
        }
      }
    ],
```

Parameters are best described in this [parameters block of the documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/#parametersDefinitionsObject).

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "pet response",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        }
      },
```

Likewise, responses are best described in the [response documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/#responsesDefinitionsObject)

```
      "default": {
        "description": "unexpected error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorModel"
        }
      }
```

Default is the [default response](http://swagger.io/specification/#responsesObject) if nothing else returns.

```
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Pranspach. I think my biggest issue is actually with the JSON schema. Can you send me any links to good sites that explain how it works?

Comment: I don't have a link, but in your example, Restaurant is defined in the "definitions" section as an Object (think Restaurant.java) with properties id, name, etc... They are "typed" by specifying their format ("Data Types" section in the swagger docs).

That Restaurant endpoint will return [ { id:1, name:"restaurant", ... } ]

Comment: I've just found the root of my problem. I checked the Javascript console in Chrome when I submit the Ajax POST and I'm getting an error saying: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present in the requested resource". I'm trying to figure out how to enable CORS on the server but it's difficult to find any resources that show to do this. I'm using swaggerize-express because that's what was used in the Azure example I followed for creating a Node.js Web API. Do you know how to do this?